# Is there a CSS only way of breaking a word on a specific non whitespace character?

Tags: css

I want to split a word (e.g. `THIS_PHRASE_HERE`) on underscores if it overflows the div it's inside, which is a fixed width. I know I can do `word-break: break-all` to split the word on any character, but that looks a little messy, especially if there's an orphan of 1 or 2 characters at the end. I'm sure I could do this with JS, but was wondering if there's a way of doing it in CSS only, something like `word-break: "_"`.

Comment: don't believe there's a CSS only way..

Comment: there is no CSS way but a HTML tag for it `<wbr>` (word break oppertunity).

Comment: No, there is currently no CSS-only way to break a word on a specific non-whitespace character. CSS provides various properties and values for controlling word wrapping and line breaking, such as word-wrap, overflow-wrap, and hyphens, but these properties are mainly focused on handling long words and controlling line breaks at whitespace characters.

Comment: Not with CSS, with JS you can insert 0 width whitespace characters to break on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently there are no way of doing only with CSS, [word-break](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break) property doesn't have that option.
You can use the html tag <[wbr](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/wbr)> to add a work break oportunity, where the browser may optionally break a line.

Comment: Thanks - you'd think there was a way of doing this, right? Weird.

Comment: Maybe an answer comes up in the next CSS update.